# An old Windows 2000 system needs SMBv1 in SAMBA - how do I enable it?

Tags: samba, windows-2000

Apparently, SAMBA no longer wants to support SMBv1, leaving an old Windows 2000 machine in our shop unable to connect.
I tried adding "min protocol = NT1"to smb.conf, but this has not helped.

Is the NT1 code completely gone?
Or what am I missing?

Updated: Here is the (revised) global section:

```
[global]
   workgroup = AFAR
   server string = Shadow (Linux/Samba Server)

   hosts allow = x.x.x.x,y.y.y.y,z.z.z.z
   disable netbios = no

   printcap = cups
   load printers = yes
   printing = cups

   log file = /var/log/samba/%m.log
   max log size = 0

   security = user
   passdb backend = tdbsam

   encrypt passwords = yes

    min protocol = NT1
    client min protocol = NT1
    server min protocol = NT1
```

My situation is that I have an old Windows 2000 machine that hosts a development environment for a legacy embedded product. It needs to mount a Linux-hosted file system in order to access the CVS code database. It has worked well for 12 years. In the last week we lost power, and upon reboot, the Win2K machine failed to mount any of its SAMBA file systems. The SAMBA host has been updated several times, and other clients have had issues with patches that caused temporary incompatibilities, but obviously the Win2K machine is not getting Windows updates.

When Win2K tries to mount the SAMBA files, it gets a generic authentication error: "Wrong username or password".

I will be looking at Wireshark traces of the failure next, but I was hoping someone else had ideas.

Samba is 4.5.14 (from Fedora 25)

Comment: @Ramhound: I added both **client min protocol = NT1** and **server min protocol = NT1** but it still fails.